# Stackoverflow is becoming less and less noob friendly nowadays

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, new-users

Stack overflow is not the same what it used to be one year before. Experience is very bad for noobs. Moderators are rigid. Recently, they closed one of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297803/book-and-assembler-to-learn-assembly-on-64-bit-pc) on assembly. They gave me two links to show that my question is duplicate. I can just laugh on those links. first one is about the assembler to use. I commented that I can't use MASM but that hardly makes any difference to them. They just want to close the question as soon as possible. 
The final comment is best. Where the mod wrote "There are emulators out there such as SPIMS for MIPS.". But can anybody tell me how a noob can know there are emulators for assembly? He could have put that for answer.
The first comment is also great, "Which book is best is completely subjective". but I never asked for the best book. I just want a book for 64 bit assembly. I think they assume lots of thing in their mind. nowadays I hardly visits stack overflow for these reasons. This site is not for noobs anymore.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the field but I tend to agree somewhat. The question *was* very broad, but it does show a scenario that isn't answered in either of the dupes ... *if* 64 bit requires a special kind of assembler, which I don't know

Comment: ... on the other hand (as shown by @Paul below) this information is terribly, terribly easy to Google.

Comment: @Eat : The question may be very broad. But I got surprised by their eagerness to close the question instead of providing solution. First he lold that my question is subjective. When I answered for that. He gave me another reason that the question is duplicate. The mod himself is unable to find a link which has answered my question.

Comment: I understand, but consider that Stack Overflow gets 3000 new questions a day. If a question doesn't stick to the site's basic rules, there will be very little willingness to help the asker out. Paul's first suggestion sounds like a good way to do this to me

Comment: it's closer to 4k questions/day -- see http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true

Comment: "terribly easy to Google.". No brother. It is not terribly easy. There are assemblers for 64 bit. But hardly anyone one of them can be used by a new user. I googled and found that FASM can be used for this. But I did not get any noob friendly tutorials for FASM. and if google the answer can be an answer, 90% questions in SO can be closed.

Comment: I can't get who is Paul here?

Comment: I mean the Paul who answered your question below.

Answer (score 33):

See

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

first of all.

This is the *entire text* of your question:

> I want to learn assembly language programming. I have a 64 bit pc with windows 7. Which book and assembler I should use for this purpose?

How much research effort did you put into your question? And how much of that research effort did you demonstrate and share in the question itself?

(do note that the first link is a *mandatory* clickthrough page for all new users when they ask questions, as well...)

You want effort from us? You put effort into your questions first, or with all due respect, take it elsewhere.

Comment: THe whole idea of internet forums is that some one has a question, they have the answer.
He never asked anyone to research the bloody thing, he was hoping that some one new off the top his head.

Now this all works nicely because in the futur, some one may google a similar question, and guess what! THe answer will be on stackoverflow!!
Yay for all!

But then you get the cronies around here, who don't want discusion, vague posts.. or heck any info at all!

Comment: we don't want lazy askers, is what we don't want. You have to give to get. Meet us halfway. Heck meet us a quarter of the friggin' way.

Comment: @Michael: SO is **not** _yet another internet forum_.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood : "take it elsewhere". Yes this is the best suggestion. I should have googled the answer instead of wasting my time at SO. But you should calculate first what requires more effort? Giving wrong reasons and closing the question or just waiting for someone with senses to answer the question.

Comment: @nara the best way to not waste your time and *ours* is for you to put some research effort into your questions. In the time it took you to type that "question" into Stack Overflow **you could have found the answer for yourself already**.

Comment: ... especially if you factor in the time spent on asking *this* question here!

Answer (score 5):

Your question was rightly closed as not constructive. It wasn't closed because it had a duplicate. It was the kind of question that shows no research effort, and can receive opinions for answers rather than fact. It would have been much better if you had searched the internet for some information on "64 bit Windows assembler" you'll be headed in the right direction. Then if you're torn in between two, ask something like:

> What are the pros and cons of these two assemblers?

Which will be more likely to receive facts as answers than asking a question in the form of:

> Which of these two assemblers is better?

or:

> Which assembler should I use?

Which will both likely be answered by people's opinions.

Comment: +1 fair enough - this is indeed easy enough to Google.

Comment: -1 can't agree with any of your three proposed questions. Without very specific details, they all three are completely subjective.

Comment: Even your preferred format will still get people's opinions.

Comment: All the three suggestions will be closed within 5 minutes.

Comment: @Mat I don't think you read my post right. I didn't propose 3 questions, I showed two examples of questions that are like his, and one suggestion of a question that will get facts as answers. Obviously none od those one-liners were meant to be stand-alone either. They are examples.

Comment: @Paul: I still disagree. "Pros and Cons" / "Does and Donts" / "Better / Worse" all require a _lot_ of context not to be subjective in general, so much so that they are near impossible to get right for SO.  They also fall rapidly into "list of stuff" type questions with N different answers, none objectively correct or incorrect.

Comment: @Mat Alright. I see that too, but I think people can generally make a list of pros and cons and keep it subjective. For example look at the list of advantages and disadvantages on YASM's wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yasm