# Why is there no "noob land"?

Tags: discussion, new-users

To start off please don't misinterpret the question.

I understand that Stack Overflow is meant to be a forum for professionals looking to get serious professional help, but I feel as if you are leaving out a whole group of people. While I may have a biased opinion being a student and not knowing nearly as much as your users I see a good deal of almost attacks against users new to field of computers and other things Stack Overflow is associated with.

A good deal of these users are posting legitimate questions that they can't find answers to and are getting almost assaulted by responses of "did you even research this" and other things making them feel like they are incompetent. The reality of the situation however is that these people sometimes don't know they've found the answer or are looking to see if there is someone out there that can explain it in a way that is less confusing.

One of the biggest positives about forums like these with people answering questions like those is they generally rephrase the answer in a less professional way that makes it easier to grasp the concepts of these ideas. Personally one of the most annoying these I have ever had happen is when doing a personal project attempting to understand some of the abilities of C++ I had people posting about how they we're just going to do my homework for me. The thing was it wasn't homework. I was a person attempting to get a better understanding of a language I didn't fully understand.

To fix the problem of these people being brutally shunned out of the community for questions that the professionals regard as "too stupid", "not worth there time", "not researched fully" or even just "plain old too basic", **is there another Stack Exchange site for new people such as students or hobbyists where they won't be judged for not knowing things and they can get help without being shunned?**

Please take this idea with an open mind and attempt to understand how frustrating it is to see a very valuable resource that will allow you to understand a complex idea and then be shunned out of it simply because the idea was to elementary.

Also - Sometimes people have put in research but they want to hear the ideas of other see what the recommend because these people usually have more experience and can say things like "Well this book while it looks good is extremely useless yet this one was wonderful". These may be opinions but they are also very useful to those that need guidance.

From what I see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105191/stackoverflow-is-becoming-less-and-less-noob-friendly-nowadays)  this idea might not be taken well but I do believe he is correct and this problem needs to be addressed.

Comment: so is not friendly who doesn't show research efforts or vampire .. there is nothing wrong with noob and **users either up vote or down vote to post not to user** imo

Comment: There are plenty of *well worded, high quality* questions from n00bs being posted. It's not the n00bness of the question that is being attacked, it's the lack of effort or quality that is lacking in so many questions.

Comment: @Lance Ooops! Sorry for stepping on your edit! I must have submitted it a fraction of a second after yours!

Comment: @Andrew, one of the most frustrating things on these sites is edits tripping over each other, it's the nature of the beast.

Comment: They are putting forth the effort however it isn't being seen. Also not understanding what they are looking for isn't not researching it's simply not knowing. Quality is another large problem where some see it as lack of quality yet in reality they just don't know. @NullPointer There is nothing wrong with a noob but more often then not members don't understand just how noob something is and how difficult some things can be. As I explained some concepts are extremely confusing and from the point of view of someone who knows the answer a quick google search will tell you and be very informative

Comment: Yet from someone who doesn't know the answer what they see is simply more confusing or not the answer they're looking for.

Comment: Also to whoever edit the is there another stack exchange site. The simple answer is no. There isn't.

Comment: A quote from the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page, with emphasis added: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. **Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs**." Now, if as you say 'legitimate questions ... are getting almost assaulted by responses of "did you even research this"' that would indeed be bad (any examples to show us?), but "did you research this" looks like a response to a question **that does not show any research**.

Comment: Related: [Question Staging SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130205/question-staging-se)

Comment: @AakashM I do not have any example due to the fact that I these are usually on others questions. And they do research but they may not believe it is the answer they were looking for. For example. I recently was wondering about vectors in C++ I found lots of answers that in retrospect were correct but I did not understand those answers. I was under the impression that vectors were simply dynamic arrays and they acted exactly like arrays. This however is sadly not true and they act more like arrays of arrays. I found many answers but in my research I did not understand that I had found it.

Comment: @Griffin: what does that have to do with the treatment of newbies on SO? Did you bring up a question on the topic that was then shot down?

Comment: I haven't brought up the question before but I when writing that the related questions came up and I noticed a good deal of the time that things like this were proposed they were treated exactly like this one is being concerning the rating even though however I am quite clear and I show previous research.

Comment: [Are votes different on Meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: Is often used yet on other SO sites it's used the same way as on this one.

Comment: @Griffin: I happened across [this question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14732960/1) (link is to original version), and I think it's an illustrative example. I wouldn't have downvoted it. But you were asking whether a particular code snippet would print out an infinite (or extremely large) number of digits- and yet you never actually tried the code to see if it would. Wouldn't that have been worthwhile research effort?

Comment: That's the thing. That wasn't the intent of the question. I knew it wouldn't keep dividing yet I couldn't think of a better example. If you look the real question comes out here "I would like to limit the amount stored in the b variable to a a set number of spaces after the decimal." My miswording of the first question was due to the fact that I was attempting to think ahead yet asking a question while it was still behind. If you look at newer version of that question I correct myself and the question ends up being a more simple "How do I limit this to only one place after the decimal point?"

Comment: @Griffin: And you'll notice that after you made that revision, your question was upvoted and the post was reopened. In other words, the system works.

Comment: @DavidRobinson You'll also notice that the reason it was upvoted and opened was that I emailed them asking to do so. In other words it doesn't.

Comment: @Griffin: Do you mean flagged, or who did you email? (And no amount of emailing anyone will get you upvotes).

Comment: @DavidRobinson Email some support thing and it did get me upvotes because they emailed me back saying "I up-voted one of your posts and it lifted the ban automatically. " So yea........ explain that.

Comment: @Griffin The question ban that was lifted has *nothing at all* to do with that question being reopened.

Comment: You said an I quote "And no amount of emailing anyone will get you upvotes" Please explain why it was able to..... also 10 closes don't magically go away.

Comment: Silence..... awkward when your wrong isn't it.

Comment: No, Griffin, he was right.  I don't think you grok SO yet.

Comment: Yet I was able to get votes....

Comment: What I grok is that a group of very knowledgeable people that are a great resource to the community are not allowing those willing and wanting to learn. There are also no accommodation set up to allow those people to do so. When these individuals attempt to ask questions and acquire information they are sent away not for real reasons but under the simple belief that haven't done enough even when they have attempted to find it out for themselves.

Comment: @Griffin: At some point you have to ask why nobody agrees with you.

Comment: @DavidRobinson As you can see from when I posted the link someone has the same feeling as me. On top of that the first vote was actually an upvote.

Comment: @DavidRobinson infact a good number of people agreed with him also.

Comment: @DavidRobinson infact http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138112/pekka (if you add all your reps up I believe he still beats you) agreed with it.

Answer (score 28):

Ignoring all of the potential arguments about what such new users should or should not be doing, there is a major problem with your proposal:

Most high-quality contributors would quite simply *avoid* that area like the plague. The overall quality in that area would be horrid, because of the lack of standards. Instead of 'training' new users how to use the site, it would 'train' new users how to *not* use the site - and probably just teach them that the site isn't really any better than some random forum.

Answer (score 17):

Andrew already posted the main reason that a "Stack Overflow for n00bs" just wouldn't work, but there are a few things in your post that I also want to address.

> A good deal of these users are posting legitimate questions that they can't find answers to and are getting almost assaulted by responses of "did you even research this" and other things making them feel like they are incompetent.

Asking "did you even research this?" is not an assault.  It's often a perfectly reasonable response to a question that's easily answered by Googling or by looking in the assigned text book.  If "what have you tried?" needs to be asked, then the OP just needs to *show* what research they've done.  They don't need to go somewhere else.

> To fix the problem of these people being brutally shunned out of the community for questions that the professionals regard as "too stupid", "not worth there time", "not researched fully" or even just "plain old too basic", is there another Stack Exchange site for new people such as students or hobbyists where they won't be judged for not knowing things and they can get help without being shunned?

People are not being "brutally shunned" for one bad question.  If you ask a n00bish question, nobody is going to hold it against you when you ask your next, *well-researched* question.  Only people who exhibit a pattern of *repeatedly* asking questions that get down-voted, closed, and deleted are actually banned from asking questions again.  Giving those people another place to ask questions seems counter-productive to the goals of Stack Overflow (increase signal-to-noise ratio, make the Internet better, etc.).

Comment: "Asking "did you even research this?" is not an assault. " It wouldn't be an assault if it wasn't posted so constantly after the initial response. Instead of one post of not researching there ends up being 4-5 and then they start talking about how horribly researching it. "People are not being "brutally shunned" for one bad question. If you ask a n00bish question, nobody is going to hold it against you when you ask your next, well-researched question." This is true yet in the confines of the question they asked they are being.

Comment: @Griffin It's posted so 'constantly' because it is needed in order to prompt the user to give more information. Astute users (newbie or not) will catch on, and begin to give that information before hand.

Comment: Also it isn't counter-productive because your helping the developing community. That community you are creating eventually understands the concepts and is able to help the ones to come. This is more of helping out the up and coming community to get on their feet. That way when they are on their feet and understand these things on a professional level they are able to help others that are at the professional level.

Comment: @Griffin My quibble with you here is that what you propose *won't help them*. There are tons of forums out there that allow this sort of thing. If that sort of thing worked, there would be no need for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Griffin We already have many pages of instructions on how to ask questions here.  We also have a process to follow when you *do* get question banned.  We are all about helping n00bs come into the community, but they need to be willing to follow those guidelines.

Comment: Yet like I said these questions were researched. Instead of giving a productive response such as first you should look into this. Give information about this. The answer is simply. You did not research this enough. Not a well constructed responce.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yet regarding the fundamentals it isn't possible to post questions the follow the instructions due to the fact that they don't have example and don't understand enough to ask propers.

Comment: @AndrewBarber There are also tons of forums out there that are just like SO. Usually however these forums are more personalized to a specific group of people but they are there for professionals who want professional responses. Also the reason these things are out there are because they are useful and needed. They wouldn't be so many of them if they weren't.

Comment: I would remember that on SO, often some people seem to apply some "theoretical rules" which are usually not applied and officially not valid. But they seem revive them sometimes, for the stupefaction of who sees them applied. It happened that I saw my comments deleted for having asked if the OP had tried something. Said this, I agree that asking what the OP tried/searched is not an assault, but it seems like that some people still need to conform.

Answer (score 6):

It pretty much depends on what you mean by being "noob friendly".

People (which may also include you) tend to confuse things. If you make a simple question, which has a simple answer, and the answer couldn't be found everywhere then your question is legitimate. If instead you ask a simple question, which has a simple answer, and this answer could be found with a simple research, then you shouldn't have asked the question.

This means that if the problem is not based on a question it is too simple or those who ask it lack knowledge. It's not simple->closed, instead it is no research->closed .

You can even replace "simple" with "hard" and that is still valid.

There some who confuse this concept, from both sides (answerers and askers). One may think : "I have asked a simple question and they've closed it", on the other side one may think: "I closed this question because it's too basic". They would both be wrong, sadly it often happens. Some people are too biased, and this is regularly associated with it being simple or too short, or too generic question with an off topic question. What you should do is just to comment, if you see that your question was legitimate, so that you did search things before asking it. If they close it as a duplicate, don't get too angry because of this, it may happens from time to time. Asking a duplicate question isn't said to be "symptom" of no research, because it may happen that you asked it with a different title from the duplicate one, so also searching with Google that problem wouldn't lead to the duplicate question. In this case accept it, and go to see the duplicate question. If the question doesn't satisfy your needs, ask to reopen it saying that the duplicate question wasn't enough to answer to your doubts. Post here if you need to debate over a closed question.

As for the last thing you ask, I think that this is the right place for asking questions even from newbies. Just ask it in a certain form, always search before asking, show your efforts and you'll be replied. Even simplest questions get an answer on this site if they're written correctly.

Comment: I believe you are right. Like I said however some people can be staring at the answer and not know it is the answer. If something is a duplicate feel free to close it because there is no reason for it. There are simple questions however that are not replied to positively simply because they are simple. This is where the problem lies.

Comment: @Griffin: If that's the case, that's a problem - and I dare say that happens sometimes. What I see happening *much more frequently* is people complaining that SO is "elitist" when they've asked a simple question **badly**, and they assume it's the simplicity of the question which has earned them the downvote, when it's actually because they didn't put any *visible* effort into asking a good question. That's why I compiled http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list. It's entirely possible to be new to a topic and still ask a good question, if you put in the effort.

Comment: @Griffin Everyone's a beginner at something or other.  Take a look at one of my [Sharepoint questions](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/54396/9561).  The answer was, I was misunderstanding how something worked.  Not understanding something doesn't get you downvotes; it's the lack of effort or clarity when you ask your question that attracts them.  My question goes, "This is my problem.  Here's how I understand it, and here's how I tested it.  They don't match.  What am I missing?".  Showing effort and research is a basic requirement of the SE network.  It's why it's better.